# Date field must cast to 'date' in Eloquent model

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

Hi I'm using **laravel nova** for create an admin panel. And I'm trying to use **Date Field**.

This is my migration,

```
$table->date('day')->nullable();
```

This is my my nova resource,

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Date::make(__('Day'), 'day'),
        ];
    }
```

This is my model,

```
class Menu extends Model
{
    use HasTranslations;

    public $translatable = ['name','description'];

    protected $fillable = [
        'name','description','typology', 'cost', 'day', 'active', 'buffet'
    ];
```

This is my error,

> Date field must cast to 'date' in Eloquent model.

Do I need to do anything in resource ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

In your model class you just need to add the following lines which describe to laravel that you must cast the day field into a date object (Carbon):

```
//Casts of the model dates
protected $casts = [
    'day' => 'date'
];
```

Check [here](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/22) someone has the same issue.

EDIT:

I have seen that your `day` column is set to `nullable` i think that your field Nova should be to like in this [post](https://github.com/laravel/nova-issues/issues/1114) :

```
public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make()->sortable(),
            Date::make(__('Day'), 'day')->nullable(),
        ];
    }
```

And we need to change the model like this,

```
protected $casts = ['day' => 'date'];
```

Comment: really sorry I did that but still issue happens :'( and do I need to add carbon?

Comment: :'( still it appears :'(

Comment: can you post the model too ? don't you have other fields with a date ?

Comment: Thanks a lot bro I found a little missing piece and added it :). I up voted and selected as correct answer it would be great help if you can approve the edit :)

Comment: No problem bro ;)